# Dispaly special characters ("@") in uitextview content

Tags: ios, uitextview, special-characters

I have to display "@" in the `UITextview` content and after to put some information.
I looked on the internet via google but I didn't find an explanation which make 
me understand the good approach.

Can you help me with some extra advice ?

Thanks !

Comment: Show the current code you have. Presumably you create the string in code so you need to use a \ but how can we currently know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do it like this:

```
     _textView.text=@"@Hi Hello";    result will be     @Hi Hello
```

However if you want to use " in the text you need to append it to backslash \

```
     _textView.text=@"@Hi \"Hello";   result will be    @Hi "Hello
```

You can enter almost all special characters without any problem, but you need to take care for the double quotes:

```
     _textView.text=@"@Hi \"Hello * ! @ # $  % ^ & ( ) _ + - [ ] ; ' {} <> ,. / ? : \" ";
```

Comment: Thanks for your response !